Integrating Third-Party Authentication in an Angular Application with Spring Boot
I am in the process of developing an application with an Angular frontend and a Spring Boot backend. I would like to delegate the management of authentication, tokens, sessions, and refresh tokens to a trusted third-party service.
I prefer to use a library or an external service so that I don’t have to manage multiple running servers.
Could you provide any advice or recommendations please ?
Thank you in advance for your help!
I heard about SuperTokens, but upon doing some research, I found that it doesn't have an SDK for Spring Boot and requires a Node.js server to run.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
